# mongodb collection lost after successful build

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am trying to seed a mongodb during the build process with docker-compose, but the import is lost Therefore I created a little example seed project on github to narrow it down Url: [Github Mongodb Seed](https://github.com/sogistuvsogistuv/dockercomposemongoseed).
After the build process the dockerimport seemed to have worked and I can tell cause I execute a small shell script (restorecheck.sh) to verify this. As soon as the "docker-compose up" is finished, the data inside the mongodb is lost.

This is an extract from the build process:

```
...
Step 7/7 : RUN mkdir -p /data/db && mongod --fork --logpath=$RESTORE/mongodb.log && sleep 10 && mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --db analysedb --collection configdata --type json --file $RESTORE/init.json --jsonArray --verbose && chmod +x $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh && $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh
 ---> Running in 815fa42de32b
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 10
child process started successfully, parent exiting
2017-10-09T04:22:40.754+0000    filesize: 248 bytes
2017-10-09T04:22:40.754+0000    using fields: 
2017-10-09T04:22:40.755+0000    connected to: 127.0.0.1
2017-10-09T04:22:40.755+0000    ns: analysedb.configdata
2017-10-09T04:22:40.755+0000    connected to node type: standalone
2017-10-09T04:22:40.755+0000    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2017-10-09T04:22:40.755+0000    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2017-10-09T04:22:40.831+0000    imported 1 document
            "name" : "analysedb",
Database is existing
[ "configdata" ]
collection found
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/analysedb
MongoDB server version: 3.4.9
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59daf99018666b44d21a378f"), "filename" : "myfile.dat", "id" : "73a5926d-2973-4b55-a3ea-d5933e5ac51c", "name" : "0.10.06", "acronym" : "ACK", "snapshotCreationDate" : "2016-04-21T18:48:21.614+02:00", "analyzed" : "true", "active" : true }
 ---> faee16091e62
Removing intermediate container 815fa42de32b
Successfully built faee16091e62
Successfully tagged mymongo:1.0.0
```

So either I forgot some sort of commit or it is due to the "Removing intermediate container". But this is not how I understood intermediate containers work. What am I missing?

Do you have any other Idea or even a solution?

As requested, this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongonew:
        build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: dockerfiles/mongodb/Dockerfile
        command: bash -c "chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock && mongod"
    volumes:
        - ./log:/log/
    image: mymongo:1.0.0
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

And this is the Dockerfile in folder dockerfiles/mongodb:

```
FROM mongo:latest

ENV RESTORE=/home/restorefolder/
RUN mkdir $RESTORE
COPY dockerfiles/mongodb/analysedb/* $RESTORE

RUN pwd
RUN cd $RESTORE
RUN mkdir -p /data/db && mongod --fork --logpath=$RESTORE/mongodb.log && sleep 10 && mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --db analysedb --collection configdata --type json --file $RESTORE/init.json --jsonArray --verbose && chmod +x $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh && $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh
#RUN chmod +x $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh && $RESTORE/restorecheck.sh

#CMD ["mongod"]
```

Comment: Post your docker-compose file

Comment: just updated the post...

Comment: Can you post `docker inspect <containerid>` of this mongo container?

Comment: It has to many lines:
https://github.com/sogistuvsogistuv/dockercomposemongoseed/blob/master/docker_inspect.txt

Comment: The problem is happening because `VOLUMES` defined in Dockerfile are auto mounted now. And the content is blank, so you are not getting what was already there. Unfortunately there is no data copied. So only solution I can think of  is to run it like this `docker run -v /data/db ....` or using `docker volume create mongodata` and then use `docker run -v mongodata:/data/db ...`

Comment: Interesting I will do some research in this direction. thx! 
What I do not understand is, how does `docker run -v...` fit into my plan to use docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

**Using answer as comments, since I need formatting**

The problem is happening because `VOLUMES` defined in `Dockerfile` are auto mounted now. And the content is blank, so you are not getting what was already there.

Unfortunately there is no data copied. So only solution I can think of is to run it like this `docker run -v /data/db ....` or using `docker volume create mongodata and then use docker run -v mongodata:/data/db ...`

Equivalent of that in `docker-compose` is

**Using Anonymous volumes**

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongonew:
        build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: dockerfiles/mongodb/Dockerfile
        command: bash -c "chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock && mongod"
    volumes:
        - ./log:/log/
        - /data/db
    image: mymongo:1.0.0
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

or

**Using Named volumes**

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongonew:
        build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: dockerfiles/mongodb/Dockerfile
        command: bash -c "chown `whoami` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock && mongod"
    volumes:
        - ./log:/log/
        - mymongodata:/data/db
    image: mymongo:1.0.0
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  mymongodata: {}
```

Comment: Still same. 2 volumes were created during build process, 
but as soon as build was done these volumes were gone. With docker-compose up two different volumes are created:
During the build there were just 2 volumes with long ids and then after compose up there is one with a long id and another named: dockercomposemongoseed_mymongodata